# Where is virtualmin default used ssl located?

Tags: ssl, webmin, virtualmin

I am trying to install SSL on a virtual server, that uses Virtualmin/Webmin. Tutorials say that SSL needs to be enabled before uploading your certificate, but when trying to enable SSL an error is returned:

> certificate file is not valid : Line 39 does not look like PEM format

The problem is that it does not say which certificate it opens or where. How could I find the location of the certificate?